# Simple problem on my jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to show 1.php on div firstresult and 1b.php to div secondresult. My code is not correct though. I want one option value to trigger two div and two php files. like to get the val and display 1.php to first and 1b.php to the second.

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#termid').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#firstresult').load(val + '.php', { value: val }).$('#secondresult').load(val + 'b.php', { value: val });
});
});
</script>

    <form>
        <select id="termid">
            <option value="">- select -</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>  
    </form>

<div id="firstresult"></div>
<div id="secondresult"></div>
```

Comment: It would probably help if you spelled secondresult correctly :P

Comment: @mispy haha done it but no :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it right - you just need to separate the two statements:

```
$('#firstresult').load(val + '.php', { value: val });
$('#secondresult').load(val + 'b.php', { value: val });
```

Comment: Thank you! I currently have the files 1.php 1b.php and 2.php . When I selected option 2, it displayed 2.php on firstresult but 1b.php remained in secondresult. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Punkis, just add a `.empty()` before the `.load(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me how to put a loading image until the results are displayed?or should i make a new question ?

Comment: @Punkis, you're better off asking a new question ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this ?](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/37wNA/) - actual loading will not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#termid').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val==1){ 
        $('#firstresult').load(val + '.php', { value: val });
    }else if(val==2){
        $('#secondresult').load(val + 'b.php', { value: val });
    }
});
});
});
```

Considering using a switch-case statement if you plan on having multiple options.

Comment: Thanks for this but I want one option value to trigger two div and two php files. like to get the val and display 1.php to first and 1b.php to the second